# Is there a toHaveBeenCalledWith in php unit test like jasmine?

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to test if a function is been call with a set of parameter like how `toHaveBeenCalledWith` work in jasmine.

Is there a way to do that in php unit test?

Comment: You can do that with mocks: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phpunit doesn't have what jasmine calls spies. But you can mock a class and set expectations on how you expect methods of that class to be called (and what they should return etc.)

Checkout [phpunit manual example 9.11.](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.SubjectTest.php)

```
public function testObserversAreUpdated()
{
    // Create a mock for the Observer class,
    // only mock the update() method.
    $observer = $this->getMockBuilder(Observer::class)
                     ->setMethods(['update'])
                     ->getMock();

    // Set up the expectation for the update() method
    // to be called only once and with the string 'something'
    // as its parameter.
    $observer->expects($this->once())
             ->method('update')
             ->with($this->equalTo('something'));

    // Create a Subject object and attach the mocked
    // Observer object to it.
    $subject = new Subject('My subject');
    $subject->attach($observer);

    // Call the doSomething() method on the $subject object
    // which we expect to call the mocked Observer object's
    // update() method with the string 'something'.
    $subject->doSomething();
}
```